# Bundling for Existing Angular 2 project (Using CLI or Web Pack)

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I have one Angular 2 Legacy project in which js is not bundled.I have tried using webpack but I am facing multiple issue. Every where on net I've found the steps to bundle for new project but nowhere mentioned actual steps for old Legacy angular project. If anyone know the exact steps Please let me know. Thanks in ad

Answer (score 0):

Install Angular CLI, create a new project using CLI, and try moving your files/components/modules to this CLI project in related directories and run the project.

Use these commands:

**1. Install Angular CLI**

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

**2. Create CLI project**

```
ng new <project_name>
```

**3. Go to project directory**

```
cd <project_name>
```

**4. Run CLI project**

```
ng serve -o
```